# Checking if an integer will be returned

Tags: ruby, integer

As part of a Ruby training exercise I'm trying to find out how many divisors the number 'n' has. I plan to write something like:

```
x = 1,  
while n > x do ___,  
n/x,   
if n/x = integer, 
puts x,   
x = x+1.
```

Obviously, that won't work. I suppose what I'm asking is how to *properly* write "if n/x is an integer, puts x."

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "`n/x` is an integer" is equivalent to "`n%x` is zero" (in Ruby, `puts x if (n % x).zero?`)

Comment: Alternatively, you might check if integer division gives the same result as the float one. `puts x if N / x == 1.0 * N / x`.

Comment: Or using rational numbers: `puts x if n.quo(x).denominator == 1`

Answer (score 1):

> how to properly write "if n/x is an integer, puts x."

You'd typically use the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) ([`%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-25) in Ruby) and check if it returns `0`:

```
6 % 1 #=> 0
6 % 2 #=> 0
6 % 3 #=> 0
6 % 4 #=> 2
6 % 5 #=> 1
```

Your pseudo code transformed into Ruby:

```
n = 6
x = 1
while n > x
  if n % x == 0
    puts x
  end
  x = x + 1
end
```

Or more idiomatic and slightly optimized: (only traversing up to `n/2`)

```
n = 6
1.upto(n/2).select { |i| n % i == 0 }
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that this returns an array. Put a `puts` in front of it in order to print its elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Ruby standard library Prime class which defines the method [Prime#prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division).

So, given a number `n = 3780`, you can get its prime factors and exponents:

```
require 'prime'

n = 2**2 * 3**3 * 5 * 7 #=> 3780
Prime.prime_division(n) #=> [[2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 1], [7, 1]]
```

You can then map the exponent, add one to each of the mapped elements and multiply the elements each other to get the number of divisors, including `1` and `n` itself:

```
Prime.prime_division(n).map{|n| n.last + 1}.inject(:*)
#=> 48
```

Here you can find how it works: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m170/wk2/numdivisors.html

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, thank you for your help!